# Слушатель прокрутки ScrollView

Tags: java, android

Есть ScrollView c расположенным внутри RelativeLayout. В приложении "Yahoo Погода" есть интересная особенность - при прокрутке экрана в момент просмотра информации о Солнце запускается анимация, рисующая местоположение солнца на небе. Как же программно отследить прокрутку ScrollView и при появлении необходимого элемента в поле видимости (на экране) запустить определенный алгоритм?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так можно определить высоту прокрутки:

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        Log.d("TAG", scrollView.getScrollY() + "")
    }
});
```

**UPD:**
Так же можно переопределить метод `onScrollChanged` у `ScrollView`, написать свой лисенер:

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private OnScrollListener listener;

    public MyScrollView (Context context) {
        this(context,null,0);
    }

    public MyScrollView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context,attrs,0);
    }

    public MyScrollView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        listener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    public interface OnScrollListener {
        void onScrollChanged(View v, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }
}
```

---

Использовать:

```
mScrollView.setOnScrollListener(new MyScrollView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(View v, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        Log.d("result", t + "");

    }
});
```