# GooglePlay тулбар нижняя часть

Tags: android

Подскажите как реализовать съезжающее (сужающееся) view как в гугл плэй на странице апп, над названием приложения? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [что-то из этого](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout) что ли?

Comment: не совсем, тут оно на тулбар влияет, а мне нужно как плеймаркете, если зайдете на любое приложение с телефона то заметите как основная картинка съезжает сужаясь вверх.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы о параллаксе, то нужно повешать слушателя на `ScrollView`, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444735/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-scrollview/444753#444753) я писал, как это сделать. Нужный `ImageView` должен быть самым верхним элементом `ScrollView`. 
Сдвигаете `ImageView` по `Y` на высоту в два раза меньшую движению `ScrollView`, я это делаю с помощью [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids), `compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0`

```
ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mImageView, scrollY / 2f);
```

если нет необходимости в API9, то метод `setTranslationY` у `ImageView`

Comment: новые инструменты из `support:design` позволяют делать все автоматически, требуется только разместить элементы на разметке - `CoordinatorLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, `AppBarLayout`. Все это хорошо упрощает код.

Comment: @pavlofff, хм, гляну)

Comment: в вопросе ссылка в первом комментарии

Comment: а можно первым размещать не только imageview, а tablelayout к примеру? что бы сделать наподобие spotify с картинкой и кнопками? работать будет?

Comment: @Дима, попробуйте, по идее да.